# About sudden drop in crawl request of our site

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors, technical-seo

Looking for some help from Google seo expert to help our company site to identify this urgent issue.
Here is the thing: the crawl request of our site experience a sudden drop on 9th, Oct. And it hasn't recovered yet. Daily crawl request drop from 6M to 60k (nearly 95%), but traffic didn't drop. This dropping trend showed in both GSC and our company's own log report. Below is the screenshot:

[image: gsc crawl drop] [image: own log report]

We have checked the server and robots file, nothing wrong. And didn't notice any google algorithm update on 9th day.
We would really appreciate it if someone can give me some advice on how to idenfity the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to firstly check somethings before any judgement on crawl requests.

1- Dont judge it too quickly and it may be a sudden drop for only one day. If it continues to be stable there that should bring up the alert.
2-Check your Average Response Time(3rd option on top-right of the GSC image you shared). Response time increase causes downtrend for crawl request.
[image: Down trend in crawl request due to average response time inceasing]

3-Check if your server is rejecting a googlebot IP or user-agent.

4-Check if your website returning 5XX or 4XX status code.